# WXR? Export from Drupal 7 - import into WordPress

Tags: import, export

I have used some of the tutorials out there to convert a Drupal 7 site over to WordPress. My problem is that I am not finding any tutorials with the lines I can use in my MySQL to convert the users,comments,tags,category table in Drupal 7 over to the wp_users table in WordPress 3+. As I said... everything else has converted perfectly, but this is the only thing left.

Answer (score 0):

Importing in WordPress per default uses the WXR Format - which is what is importable using the default WordPress importer plugin that you can use via

```
Admin
>> Tools
>> Import
>> WordPress
```

As there (IIRC) is no Drupal export standard, you will have to convert your content into the WXR format. To export in the needed format, you will have to ask at [drupal.se].

WXR basically looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
     xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
     xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
    >

    <channel>
        <title>Your title</title>
        <link>http://example.com</link>
        <description>Foo</description>
        <pubDate>Wed, 20 Mar 2014 12:09:12 +0000</pubDate>
        <language>en-US</language>
        <wp:wxr_version>1.2</wp:wxr_version>
        <wp:base_site_url>http://example.com</wp:base_site_url>
        <wp:base_blog_url>http://example.com</wp:base_blog_url>

        <wp:author><wp:author_id>1</wp:author_id><wp:author_login>manovotny</wp:author_login><wp:author_email>manovotny@gmail.com</wp:author_email><wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[Michael Novotny]]></wp:author_display_name><wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[Michael]]></wp:author_first_name><wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[Novotny]]></wp:author_last_name></wp:author>
        // ... repeat ...

        <wp:category><wp:term_id>107</wp:term_id><wp:category_nicename>alignment</wp:category_nicename><wp:category_parent></wp:category_parent><wp:cat_name><![CDATA[Alignment]]></wp:cat_name><wp:category_description><![CDATA[Posts in this category test image and text alignment.]]></wp:category_description></wp:category>
        // ... repeat ...
        <wp:tag><wp:term_id>132</wp:term_id><wp:tag_slug>8bit</wp:tag_slug><wp:tag_name><![CDATA[8BIT]]></wp:tag_name><wp:tag_description><![CDATA[Tags posts about 8BIT.]]></wp:tag_description></wp:tag>
        // ... repeat ...
        <wp:tag><wp:term_id>129</wp:term_id><wp:tag_slug>articles</wp:tag_slug><wp:tag_name><![CDATA[Articles]]></wp:tag_name><wp:tag_description><![CDATA[Tags posts about Articles.]]></wp:tag_description></wp:tag>
        // ... repeat ...
        <wp:term><wp:term_id>144</wp:term_id><wp:term_taxonomy>nav_menu</wp:term_taxonomy><wp:term_slug>long-menu</wp:term_slug><wp:term_name><![CDATA[Long Menu]]></wp:term_name></wp:term>
        <wp:term><wp:term_id>145</wp:term_id>

        <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.5.1</generator>

        <item>
            <title>canola2</title>
            <link>http://wptest.io/demo/post-format-gallery/canola2/</link>
            <pubDate>Mon, 10 Jan 2011 13:17:54 +0000</pubDate>
            <dc:creator>manovotny</dc:creator>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">http://wptest.io/demo/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/canola2.jpg</guid>
            <description></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
            <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec mollis. Quisque convallis libero in sapien pharetra tincidunt. Aliquam elit ante, malesuada id, tempor eu, gravida id, odio. Maecenas suscipit, risus et eleifend imperdiet, nisi orci ullamcorper massa, et adipiscing orci velit quis magna.]]></excerpt:encoded>
            <wp:post_id>611</wp:post_id>
            <wp:post_date>2011-01-10 06:17:54</wp:post_date>
            <wp:post_date_gmt>2011-01-10 13:17:54</wp:post_date_gmt>
            <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
            <wp:ping_status>closed</wp:ping_status>
            <wp:post_name>canola2</wp:post_name>
            <wp:status>inherit</wp:status>
            <wp:post_parent>555</wp:post_parent>
            <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
            <wp:post_type>attachment</wp:post_type>
            <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
            <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
            <wp:attachment_url>http://wptest.io/demo/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/canola2.jpg</wp:attachment_url>
            <wp:postmeta>
                <wp:meta_key>_wp_attached_file</wp:meta_key>
                <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[2011/01/canola2.jpg]]></wp:meta_value>
            </wp:postmeta>
            <wp:postmeta>
                <wp:meta_key>_wp_attachment_metadata</wp:meta_key>
                <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:5:{s:5:"width";i:640;s:6:"height";i:480;s:4:"file";s:19:"2011/01/canola2.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:3:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:19:"canola2-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:19:"canola2-300x225.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:225;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"post-thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:19:"canola2-624x468.jpg";s:5:"width";i:624;s:6:"height";i:468;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";d:5.5999999999999996;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:18:"Canon PowerShot G2";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:1094915268;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:7:"16.8125";s:3:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";s:9:"0.0015625";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}]]></wp:meta_value>
            </wp:postmeta>
            <wp:postmeta>
                <wp:meta_key>_wp_attachment_image_alt</wp:meta_key>
                <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[canola]]></wp:meta_value>
            </wp:postmeta>
        </item>
        // ... repeat ...

    </channel>
</rss>
```

*Example extracted from the [WPTest.io GitHub](https://github.com/manovotny/wptest) repository.*

You will to alter the output to this, but basically it should not be a problem. You could also fetch the import from a RSS-Feed (just had finished a plugin doing that), but it is far more work than altering the output in Drupal as there are modules for that. Keep in mind that it is extremely important to get the namespace right. Else you will fail gracefully.

Comment: ok, but this site not work [drupal.se]. ??

Comment: are this steps convert all my content and user to my wp ??

Comment: @user3626111 What? When I click the link, I get to [Drupal.se]... and I don't know if that is the only step. Depends on your content.

Comment: i install it but how can i do that !!

Comment: First: No need to shout and use more than (or even one) exclamation mark. Second: You installed _what_ ? And "how can I do (...)" what? What did you install? How can you do what?

Comment: Sorry, [Drupal.se] seems to work to me but _what does that have to do with your site or your issue_?

Comment: i need now to get wxr how can i do that ??

Comment: Go ask on [Drupal.se] on how to export _from Drupal_.

Comment: Still don't know what the connection is to [Drupal.se]. Are you ___scraping___ [Drupal.se]?

Answer (score 0):

There's a great plugin called WP All Import that can take data out of any content management system and import it into WordPress, allowing you to map fields from one CMS to WordPress' default fields. They have a user import tool as well, though I think it may be a premium upgrade. Search for it in the plugin library.